# In Forth is the top parameter to ERASE a number of cells or a number of bytes?

Tags: forth

As the title suggests, in Forth:

Does:

```
1024 4 ERASE
```

Zero out 4 bytes begining at address 1024, or 4 cells (4x4=16 bytes in a 32-bit Forth) ?

I can't find any documentation that is entirely clear.

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: In `erase` the count is bytes.  Most of the block of memory words take addresses and counts in bytes.  There are exceptions for processors with unusual memory unit sizes.  12 bit processors etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the word `ERASE ( addr u -- )` the topmost argument `u` is the number of *address units*.

It's due to the [the specification](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/ERASE) for this word:

> clear all bits in each of *u* consecutive address units of memory beginning at *addr*.

Usually the address unit size is one octet (byte).

So the phrase `1024 4 ERASE` will erase 4 bytes in a byte-addressed machine.
To erase 4 cells beginning at the address 1024 you have to say `1024  4 cells erase`.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.